# using Redis python read in messages already being sent to redis

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redis-py

A system I'm working on currently is receiving messages in redis. I would like to write a python script that can read in those messages , modify them and return them to a different channel/key in redis.

For example:

```
 redis-cli  -a 'redis' monitor | grep '"pushName"'
```

will return :

```
1707963448.404618 [0 192.168.86.75:51520] "LPUSH" "pushName" "{\"uuid\":"be70\"...,{}}
```

How do I subscribe to get the messages from `pushName` because when I try to do this

```
mobile = r.pubsub()
mobile.subscribe('pushName')
for message in mobile.listen():
    print(message)
```

Nothing displays execept for :

```
{'type': 'subscribe', 'pattern': None, 'channel': 'pushName', 'data': 1}
```

. I already know my connection criteria is fine because I can get a list of the channels when I do this:

```
index_list = []
for key in r.scan_iter('*'):
    index_list.append(key)
```

But messages are flying when I do :

```
 redis-cli  -a 'redis' monitor | grep '"pushName"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing debug output with messages, with Redis LISTs and with Redis Pub/Sub.

If your other (real) code is doing LPUSH operations it is appending items to a Redis LIST.

Those LPUSH operations will show up in your `redis-cli monitor` command because that is a debugging tool showing you all Redis internal operations.

The LPUSH commands (which operate on a Redis LIST) will not show up when you **subscribe** to Redis Pub/Sub because that is a completely separate feature of Redis and you will only see messages when you **subscribe** to a topic and when somebody **publishes** on that topic... but nobody is doing any publishing as such, they are only doing LPUSH to a LIST.

Comment: That makes sense, I was doing a manual push and I can see the message appear. In that case is there a way to see the messages in List?

Comment: Thinking of items in a list as messages is maybe not the most helpful - they are just items in a list. All the commands related to pushing items onto a list or viewing/removing them are here https://redis.io/commands/?group=list All the commands available for Pub/Sub are listed here https://redis.io/commands/?group=pubsub  So, you can view some entries in a list with LRANGE, or remove them with LPOP. There's also RPOP for removing from the right end and BRPOP for blocking removes that wait till an item arrives.

Comment: Looking into it more that is exactly what is happening it is just a lpush to list, hence I cant subscribe. I looked through all the commands but there is nothing that just reads the items as it comes in without deleting it. I don't want to delete the items because other things are reading from that list. I actually want to read it, transform it with python, then concurrently do a separate LPUSH to a different key for logstash to read (not sure if im explaining this well) The lpush would be handled by the script

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could adapt things so they work more like you are expecting. If you want to be notified every time there is an LPUSH onto a LIST, you could change your LPUSH to a MULTI/EXEC transaction that does the LPUSH and then PUBLISHES a message to notify all interested parties in one single transaction . That would make your sender look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from time import sleep
import redis
import numpy as np

# Redis connection
r = redis.Redis(host='192.168.0.10', port=6379, db=0)

# Pub/sub connection
p = r.pubsub()

# Empty list at start of each run
r.delete('myList')

# Push 10 items to Redis LIST, publishing that they are available
N = 10
for i in range(N):
    print(f'DEBUG: Publishing item {i} and notifying subscribers')
    # Start pipeline, i.e. MULTI/EXEC transaction
    pipe = r.pipeline()
    pipe.lpush('myList', i)
    pipe.publish('notifications',f'LPUSHed to myList')
    pipe.execute()
    sleep(1)
```

Then your receiver might look like this, subscribing to the notifications stream, and grabbing the LIST when notified:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from time import time, sleep
import redis
import numpy as np

def msgHandler(message):
    """Called whenever a message is published"""
    print(message)
    # See what's in our LIST
    items = r.lrange('myList',0,100)
    print(items)
    # You could put the items into a regular Python queue here for main program to read

# Redis connection
r = redis.Redis(host='192.168.0.10', port=6379, db=0)

# Subscribe to notifications and register callback for when messages arrive
pubsub = r.pubsub(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
pubsub.subscribe(**{'notifications': msgHandler})
# Start a background message receiver
# See https://redis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced_features.html
thread = pubsub.run_in_thread(sleep_time=0.001)

# Do something else for 15 seconds
endTime = time() + 15
while time() < endTime:
    print('Waiting for data:')
    sleep(0.3)

# Stop the redis pub/sub listener
thread.stop()
```

When you run the receiver, it looks like this:

```
Waiting for data:
Waiting for data:
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'notifications', 'data': b'LPUSHed to myList'}
[b'0']
Waiting for data:
Waiting for data:
Waiting for data:
Waiting for data:
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'notifications', 'data': b'LPUSHed to myList'}
[b'1', b'0']
Waiting for data:
Waiting for data:
Waiting for data:
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'notifications', 'data': b'LPUSHed to myList'}
[b'2', b'1', b'0']
...
...
Waiting for data:
Waiting for data:
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'notifications', 'data': b'LPUSHed to myList'}
[b'9', b'8', b'7', b'6', b'5', b'4', b'3', b'2', b'1', b'0']
Waiting for data:
```

---

Note that there are actually 3 ways of waiting for messages you are subscribed to and they are described [here](https://redis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced_features.html#). Basically, you can use:

```
while True:
    message = p.get_message()
    if message:
        # do something with the message
    time.sleep(0.001)  # be nice to the system :)
```

Or you can use:

```
for message in p.listen():
    # do something with the message
```

Or you can use a thread like I did.

---

Note that I am using a pipeline (MULTI/EXEC) for 2 reasons:

- it is an atomic transaction, so we know the item will be pushed on the list before the PUBLISH
- there is less overhead/latency because it is a single round-trip to the server, rather than one round-trip per operation

Note that you can chain the pipeline elements together, so that the 4-line pipeline in my sender code becomes:

```
r.pipeline().lpush('myList', i).publish('notifications',f'LPUSHed to myList').execute()
```

Comment: Ah the one thing is I don't have control of is the system doing the LPUSH to redis. Ill have to look into anyway I can make MULTI/EXEC happen, that would be nice to then get to a publish point, this example would be great